# Cannot autowire service "App\Controller\MainController": argument "$session" of method "__construct()"

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, web, shopping-cart

There is my MainController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\ShopCart;
use App\Entity\ShopItem;
use App\Repository\ShopItemRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Config\Framework\SessionConfig;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class MainController extends AbstractController
{

    private SessionInterface $session;

    /**
     * @param SessionInterface $session
     */
    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session)
    {

        $this->session = $session;
        $this->session->start();
    }


    public function debug($data)
    {
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($data) . '</pre>';
    }

    #[Route('shop/list', name: 'List')]
    public function shopList(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, ShopItemRepository $shopItemRepository): Response
    {
        $result = $shopItemRepository->findAll();
        return $this->render('shop-list.html.twig', [
            'shoes' => $result,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @param int $shopItem
     * @return Response
     */
    #[Route('/shop/item{id<\d+>}', name: 'shopItem')]
    public function shopItem(ShopItem $shopItem)
    {
        return $this->render('shop-item.html.twig', [
            'title' => $shopItem->getTitle(),
            'description' => $shopItem->getDescription(),
            'price' => $shopItem->getPrice(),
        ]);
    }


    #[Route('/', name: 'Home')]
    public function homepage(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('homepage.html.twig');
    }

    /**
     * @param int $shopItem
     * @return Response
     */
    #[Route('/shop/cart/add/{id<\d+>}', name: 'shopCartAdd')]
    public function shopCartAdd(ShopItem $shopItem, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $sessionId = $this->session->getId();
        dd($sessionId);
//        $shopCart = new ShopCart();
//        $shopCart->setShopItem($shopItem);
//        $shopCart->setSessionId($sessionId);
//        $shopCart->setCount(1);

    }

    #[Route('/shop/cart', name: 'ShopCart')]
    public function shopCart(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('shopCart.html.twig');
    }

}
```

and when I try to dd I receive

> Cannot autowire service "App\Controller\MainController": argument
> "$session" of method "__construct()" needs an instance of
> "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface" but this
> type has been excluded from autowiring.

Use Symfony 6.2.7

I try to change SessionInterface on Session or other services but it doesn't help

Comment: Two seconds of searching ~ https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-3-session-service-deprecation

Answer (score 5):

Since Symfony 5.3, SessionInterface was deprecated (https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-3-session-service-deprecation).

You need to inject `RequestStack` and call `getSession()` method:

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class SomeService
{
    private $requestStack;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        $session = $this->requestStack->getSession();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would caution against accessing the session in the constructor because of possible timing issues.  The session might not be available when the controller is instantiated.  Safer to pull it when needed.  In fact since it is a controller then the best solution is to inject the $request object into the action methods and pull the session from it.

Comment: Was it supposed to be 
$requestStack->getSession();  ?

Comment: Thanks @ShanjayG, now it's more clear